# WPF Popup with rounded corners at the bottom only

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2008, popup, .net-3.5

I wonder if it is possible to apply rounded corner to WPF popup bottom corners only.

I know it is possible to apply rounded corners to all WPF popup corners, for example, [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0f6ec090-54f8-44bf-991b-94a049934a65/rounded-corner-popup?forum=wpf), but to only ones I am not sure. So is it possible? if so, could you provide a little example?

Comment: CornerRadius="0,0,10,10" try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am providing template customize as per need

```
<Style x:Key="PopupContentStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2" 
                         CornerRadius="0,0,20,20" Width="60" Height="60">

                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

And then

```
   <Popup>
        <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource PopupContentStyle}">

        </ContentControl>
    </Popup>
```